# How to remove Distinct values from a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to remove only **distinct values** from a list using LINQ.

My code-

```
List<MyStudents> studentsList = new List<MyStudents>();

public class MyStudents
{
     private string student;
     private int age;

     public string Student
     {
         get { return student; }
         set { student = value; }
     }

     public int Age
     {
         get { return age; }
         set { age = value; }
     }
}
```

I tried-

```
studentsList.RemoveAll(o => o.Student).Distinct();
```

But this doesn't work and displays an error-

> Cannot convert Lambda expression to intended delegate because some of
>   the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

PN: I prefer removing distinct items from existing list than creating an a new list with distinct values

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want a list where each element appears at least twice?

Comment: Can you please provide an example set and example result set? I do not fully understand your question.

Comment: Do you mean that an item is added twice? or do you mean there are two different items with the same values.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you guys. I have a list<t> of students that contain names such as Dolly, John, Dolly, Peter, Dolly, Tom, Daisy, Peter. I want to remove all non-duplicate items and get only distinct items. Result should be like this: Dolly, Dolly, Peter

Comment: "I prefer removing distinct items from existing list than creating an a new list with distinct values", this is not possible with LINQ. LINQ always creates copies of collections.
And this is most often the better way, and modifying an existing collection does not give you any advantage. It does the same thing internally, or it is even slower by moving a lot of elements several times.

Comment: Yes, right @Joelius

Comment: Why is the example result `Dolly, Dolly, Peter` and not `Dolly, Peter`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I want Dolly, Peter.. Not Dolly, Dolly, Peter... Sorry again

Answer (score 1):

If you've implemented `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for `Student`, you can try *Linq* `GroupBy` followed by `SelectMany`:

```
 studentsList = studentsList
   .GroupBy(o => o.Student)            // Groups of same students
   .Where(group => group.Count() >= 2) // Students appear at least twice
   .SelectMany(group => group)         // Ungroup (flatten) to IEnumerable<Student> 
   .ToList();                          // Materialized as List
```

If you haven't implemented `Equals` and `GetHashCode` you have to invent the grouping key, e.g.:

```
 studentsList = studentsList
   .GroupBy(o => new { // Student are equal if and only if they have same
      o.Student.Name,  // Name 
      o.Student.Age,   // and Age
    }) 
   .Where(group => group.Count() >= 2) 
   .SelectMany(group => group)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: How about the age?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would suggest you use a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Remember to always try and match your data structure to the problem you're trying to solve. Consider this, would you try and put a screw in your wall with a hammer? Sure, it's possible, but not optimal.

If you're hard stuck on using LINQ and Lists to solve this problem, you can just call .Distinct() on your list and it will return the distinct elements.

Comment: A Hashset only works on equal object instances, not two different instances with the same data.

Comment: So you either bake up your own HashSet quick, or you can provide a custom IEqualityComparer.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you should always strive to use the right tool for the job. Use a HashSet when the collection should always hold only distinct stuff. It also tells the programmer that you cant add duplicates to it. Use a normal List<T> and .Distinct() ont it when you will have to add duplicates and remove duplicates later. The intention matters.

Answer (score 0):

First take all values that appear at least twice:

```
var atLeastTwicePresent = studentsList
    .Select(sObj => sObj.Student)
    .Where(s => studentsList.Where(sObj => sObj.Student == s).Count() > 1);
```

Then take distinct values from this set:

```
var distinctAtLeastTwice = atLeastTwicePresent.Distinct().ToList();
```

And you should have the Distinct Student names that appear at least twice in your list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only the students that occur at least twice in your result, try grouping them and filter the groups based on the count:

```
studentsList.GroupBy(s => s.Student).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.First())
```

or

```
from s in studentsList
group s by s.Student into g
where g.Count() > 1
select g.First()
```

Comment: Now you are displaying all student which are duplicated in the list. what about the non-duplicates?

Comment: I thought that was the OP's request according to the comments: `Dolly, John, Dolly, Peter, Dolly, Tom, Daisy, Peter` should become `Dolly, Peter`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the items by the key you want. With a `new { }` you could create a key using the linq group.
Then, instead of selecting the key *(which is an anonymous class, which you don't want)* you select the first in the group.

The idea of an anonymous class is, that the group compares all properties, so it can be group. *(that's why you can't group on the MyStudents class)*

You could try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class MyStudents
{
     private string student;
     private int age;

     public string Student
     {
         get { return student; }
         set { student = value; }
     }

     public int Age
     {
         get { return age; }
         set { age = value; }
     }
}
```

---

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // some testdata...
        var students = new List<MyStudents>
        {
            new MyStudents { Student = "John", Age = 17 },
            new MyStudents { Student = "Mary", Age = 18 },
            new MyStudents { Student = "John", Age = 17 },
            new MyStudents { Student = "Hank", Age = 20 },
        };


        var newList = students

           // The whole idea is, group the list by creating a key.
           .GroupBy(o => new {o.Student, o.Age})
           // you don't want to select the key, because it's an anonymous class
           // So select the first item which was added to the group.
           .Select(o => o.First())
           // create a new list.
           .ToList();

        // present them         
        foreach(var s in newList)
            Console.WriteLine("Student: "+s.Student+", Age: "+s.Age);
    }
}}
```

Here is a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/33iedh)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example: use list.Distinct().ToList();

```
// List with duplicate elements.
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);
        list.Add(3);
        list.Add(3);
        list.Add(4);
        list.Add(4);
        list.Add(4);

        foreach (int value in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", value);
        }

        // Get distinct elements and convert into a list again.
        List<int> distinct = list.Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (int value in distinct)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", value);
        }
    }
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e0oGfP)

---

Using .destinct for classes makes a comparer-method necessary: see here.
but it have to be a instance of IEqualityComparer !

```
class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>  
{
            public bool Equals(Product x, Product y) {
                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                    return false;

                return x.Make == y.Make && x.Model == y.Model;
            }
            public int GetHashCode(Product product) {
                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;
                int hashProductName = product.Make == null ? 0 : product.Make.GetHashCode();
                int hashProductCode = product.Model.GetHashCode();
                return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
            }
 }

**The Distinct operator has an overload method that lets you pass an instance of IEqualityComparer.** So for this approach we created a class “ProductComparer” that implements the IEqualityCompaper. Here’s the code to use it:


if (!IsPostBack) {  
                GridView1.DataSource = GetProducts()
                                       .Distinct(new ProductComparer());
                GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: This is a direct value type, what about a class with different properties?

Comment: Using .destinct for classes makes a comparer-method necessary: see above, but it have to be a instance of IEqualityComparer !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the unique Student, then you simply need to select distinct from your list.

something like this: 
studentsList.DistinctBy(x => x.id);